# Concatenate Strings and Variables of two conditions while iterating in python

Tags: python, concatenation

I have an iteration over a dataframe, but for the example here I used a list.

```
seq = [0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
box = []

for i in range(1, len(seq)):
    if seq[i] > seq[i-1]:
        box.append(seq[i])
    else:
        box.append(seq[i-1]+10)

box
```

Now i would like to add to each appended value a string prefix like this:
For all values from the If statement letter 'A-'
For all values from else statement letter 'B-'

My desired output is:

```
[B-10, A-0, A-1, A-2, B-12, B-11, B-10......
```

I tried it with .join and with simple comma or + inside the append method, but none of it works.
Any suggestions how to accomplish this ?

Comment: You cannot expect to just prepend a string prefix to your values, because the values are not strings. Having fixed that, the output necessarily will look different, because Python will display strings inside the list using quotation marks.

Comment: It can be done but your list will have strings instead of integers. @Nico Müller has given solution for what you want already.

Comment: I don't understand how your desired output is supposed to come, could you please explain further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `f-string` literal to add the related letter:

```
seq = [0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
box = []

for i in range(1, len(seq)):
    if seq[i] > seq[i-1]:
        box.append(f"A-{seq[i]}")
    else:
        box.append(f"B-{seq[i-1]+10}")

print(box)
OUT: ['B-10', 'A-0', 'A-1', 'A-2', 'B-12', 'B-11', 'B-10', 'B-9', 'B-8', 'B-7', 'B-6', 'A--4', 'A--3', 'A--2', 'A--1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Idiotic one-liner:

```
box = map(lambda p: "A-" + str(p[1]) if p[1] > p[0] else "B-" + str(p[0] + 10), [(seq[i-1], seq[i]) for i,_ in enumerate(seq[:])][1:])
```

But in all seriousness just use string concatenation, but convert the integer value to string before concatenating:

```
seq = [0, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
box = []

for i in range(1, len(seq)):
    if seq[i] > seq[i-1]:
        box.append("A-" + str(seq[i]))
    else:
        box.append("B-" + str(seq[i-1]+10))

print (box)
```